# How to reposition cursor while editing EditText field which is formatted like US currency- Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, currency-formatting

I am formatting edit text field as per US currency format, where while typing number in a field, let's say "12345678" it appears like "12,345,678".
For this I have used `TextWatcher` and on `afterTextChanged(...)` method I am formatting the entered text like:

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String str = editable.toString();
        String number = str.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        if (number.equals(previousNumber) || number.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        previousNumber = number;

        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));

        String formattedString = formatter.format(number);
        editText.setText(formattedString);
    }
```

Also, I am using `onSelectionChanged(...)` callback method like:

```
 @Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    this.setSelection(selStart);
}
```

But here this 'selStart' doesn't return the actual length of number as it excludes the number of "," in every currency.
For example: for "12,345,678" it returns count as 8 instead of 10.
That's why I am not able to place my cursor at the end of the field.

Following is the code of custom EditText, which I am using:

```
public class CurrencyEditText extends AppCompatEditText {
private static final int MAX_LENGTH = 16;
private static final int MAX_DECIMAL_DIGIT = 2;
private static String prefix = "";
private CurrencyTextWatcher currencyTextWatcher = new CurrencyTextWatcher(this, prefix);

public CurrencyEditText(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public CurrencyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.editTextStyle);
}

public CurrencyEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    this.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
}

@Override
protected void onFocusChanged(boolean focused, int direction, Rect previouslyFocusedRect) {
    super.onFocusChanged(focused, direction, previouslyFocusedRect);
    if (focused) {
        this.addTextChangedListener(currencyTextWatcher);
    } else {
        this.removeTextChangedListener(currencyTextWatcher);
    }
    handleCaseCurrencyEmpty(focused);
}

private void handleCaseCurrencyEmpty(boolean focused) {
    if (!focused) {
        if (getText().toString().equals(prefix)) {
            setText("");
        }
    }
}

private static class CurrencyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {
    private final EditText editText;
    DecimalFormat formatter;
    private String previousNumber;
    private String prefix;
    Context mContext;

    CurrencyTextWatcher(EditText editText, String prefix) {
        this.editText = editText;
        this.prefix = prefix;
        formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        String str = editable.toString();
        String number = str.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        if (number.equals(previousNumber) || number.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        previousNumber = number;

        String formattedString = prefix + formatNumber(number);
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.setText(formattedString);
        //handleSelection();
        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }

    private String formatNumber(String number) {
        if (number.contains(".")) {
            return formatDecimal(number);
        }
        return formatInteger(number);
    }

    private String formatInteger(String str) {
        BigDecimal parsed = new BigDecimal(str);
        return formatter.format(parsed);
    }

    private String formatDecimal(String str) {
        if (str.equals(".")) {
            return "0.";
        }
        BigDecimal parsed = new BigDecimal(str);
        DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#,##0." + getDecimalPattern(str),
                new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
        formatter.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.DOWN);
        return formatter.format(parsed);
    }

    private String getDecimalPattern(String str) {
        int decimalCount = str.length() - str.indexOf(".") - 1;
        StringBuilder decimalPattern = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < decimalCount && i < MAX_DECIMAL_DIGIT; i++) {
            decimalPattern.append("0");
        }
        return decimalPattern.toString();
    }

    /*private void handleSelection() {
        if (editText.getText().length() <= MAX_LENGTH) {
            editText.setSelection(editText.getText().length());
        }
    }*/
}

@Override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    this.setSelection(selStart);
}
```

}

I don't want to use `this.setSelection(lengthOfTheEnteredText)` because it created issue when you edit the field!
What could be the reason that `onSelectionChanged(...)` does not consider the count of "," present in number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After exploring more on this issue, I have found the solution. Where I am calculating the cursor position. I have removed `onSelectionChanged(...)` method from my code and I am handling selection in`afterTextChanged(...)` method. In the following code I have made changes in `afterTextChanged(...)` :

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        String str = editable.toString();
        String number = str.replaceAll("[,]", "");
        if (number.equals(previousNumber) || number.isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }
        previousNumber = number;

        int startText, endText;
        startText = editText.getText().length();

        int selectionStart = editText.getSelectionStart();

        String formattedString = prefix + formatNumber(number);
        editText.removeTextChangedListener(this);
        editText.setText(formattedString);
        endText = editText.getText().length();

        int selection = (selectionStart + (endText - startText));
        editText.setSelection(selection);

        editText.addTextChangedListener(this);
    }
```